# Heroku doesn't display icon that is displayed locally

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an Icon that is meant to clear the search field by clicking it.  It works and has been working both in production on Heroku and in test locally.  Heroku quit displaying the Icon in production, now only displaying alternative text which means that Icon could not be loaded.  It still displays fine locally.  I don't know what changed to cause this and I cannot find a fix.  Any advice much appreciated.

The error is (with domain name changed):

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://ucf.myapp.com/assets/small_x2.png"
```

In an attempt at a fix, I tried setting the following in production.rb to no avail:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.serve_static_files  = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

Prior to pushing to Heroku, I issue:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Afterwards, just to be sure, I have tried:

```
heroku run rake assets:clean
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

HTML:

```
<img id="theImg" class="clrSearch" alt="clear" src="/assets/small_x2.png">
```

JavaScript in my js.erb file that inserts it because it is within generated HTML:

```
$('#carstable_filter').append('<img id="theImg" class="clrSearch" alt="clear" src="<%= image_url("small_x2.png") %>" />');
```

Initial location of image:

```
/app/assets/images/small_x2.png
```

Public location of image:

```
/public/assets/small_x2-7fae117327e56b60d98872466ab71b3b.png
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to login to heroku using their cmd line tool and then run: heroku run rake assets:clobber followed by heroku run rake assets:precompile.  I believe you have a zombie asset.

Comment: @ilanberci Okay, that fixed it.  Please post as answer so I can accept.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't want to post as answer as I wasn't entirely sure based off the evidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to login to heroku using their cmd line tool and then run: heroku run rake assets:clobber followed by heroku run rake assets:precompile.

I believe you have a zombie asset.